# UIScrollView in UIView not scrolling through ENTIRE content

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, frame, contentsize

Currently I am having a very trivial issue with my UIScrollView that lies within a UIViewController's UIView.

At the moment, I am using a xib file because alot of the info that I am putting inside of the UIScrollView is way too much for me to code.... (ALOT OF INFO, IMAGES, blah blah blah) but their all static.

This is the code I have used to add the UIScrollView to the UIViewController's UIView:

```
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
_scrollView.delegate = self;
_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 7 );
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
```

As you can see, the UIScrollView is LARGE!!!

I set it's content size to 7 times the size of the UIView AND set the delegete method to conform to the UIViewController.

Now, I am able to scroll perfectly BUT I am unable to scroll through the entire UIScrollView's content, even though I set it's content size to A LARGE amount!!!

What the heck am I doing wrong? :(

I also commented out this:

```
//_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, 2389)];
```

But when I use (^) line of code in comparison to the below (/) line of code.... No scrolling can be made....

```
 _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
```

What am I doing wrong?! /sob....

Thank you!

EDIT:

The UIScrollView is now HALF THE SIZE of the UIView in xib.....Everything was setup in xib as well... this is ALL the CODE there is to be seen...

If you want some snapshots... here....

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

The UIScrollview in the first picture is scrolled down ALL THE WAY.....

I also NSLOG(@"self.view.bounds.size.height * 7) -> I get 2000+

Answer (score 0):

Well because I cant see all of your code or its results I can only assume that the UIScrollView is larger then the screen.

This means that some of the content is hidden outside the bounds of the screen.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I just resized the UIScrollView within my UIView to be half the size of the UIView..... still nothing.... I'm not able to scroll through the entire content, just a portion. I also set my content size to 10000.... still nothing.... Must be something really dumb Im doing wrong cuz this is making me pissed. One of the simplest objectives in my app and I can't even do it

Comment: I hate IB, rather do everything the HARDER way... programatically

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to place all of the views directly in the scroll view.
try putting them into one view that only it lives directly within the scroll view.

Comment: .... So swap the views? UiView within UiscrollView? I just tried that and .... theres more to it if any of that were to work...

Comment: And also, how is that a bad idea? a UIview that contains a UIScrollview object... I did it in my main view controller no problem.... its just working with xibs is making it complicated :P